# Generating tile index from LAS dataset in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, tiles, lidar, las

I need to generate a tile index in ArcGIS from an LAS Dataset.

When you create an LAS Dataset, the map displays a footprint-like feature. These polygons contain the LAS file reference and you can identify the file name. Is there a way to save this as a polygon feature?

I essentially need the spatial location of the LAS files with associated file name as a field in the attribute table.

There are 800+ tiles so manually creating this is not preferred.

Comment: Have you tried feature class to polygon tool on that "layer"?

Comment: I actually found an answer,
The "Point File Information" tool does exactly what I wanted:

"Generates statistical information about one or more point files in a polygon or multipatch output." - From ESRI resources.

Answer (score 2):

I actually found an answer, The `Point File Information` tool does exactly what I wanted. From ESRI resources:

> Generates statistical information about one or more point files in a polygon or multipatch output.